# swift UserDefaults return nil as NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have multi line texts and i save them UserDefaults. When i want to get the text sometimes return nil. But there is a text in it. How can i do that the nil does not return?

```
var savedReports: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    if let sR = defaults.object(forKey: "savedReports") as? NSMutableArray {
        savedReports = sR.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserDefaults` API will always return immutable arrays. You want:

```
var savedReports: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

if let sR = defaults.object(forKey: "savedReports") as? NSArray {
    savedReports = sR.mutableCopy()
}
```

Comment: Why not use Swift types instead of Foundation types?

Comment: @LeoDabus uh, sorry, haven't noticed that. Then just a sad use of Foundation instead of Swift

Comment: @Xcoder123 The Swift version is independent of using Swift vs Foundation types.  I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: I could have used Swift types, and that's probably what I would do in most cases. I don't think it matters very much here, `NSArray` vs. `[AnyObject]`. Anyway, I just copied the original code sample and edited to work.